# Limit involving logarithms and exponentials

Tags: limits, analysis

How do I calculate:

$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\left(1-e^{\left(\frac{t+ \log^2(n)}{t-\log(n)}\right)}\right)^n$$

It's from a Statistics exercise, I haven't done analysis for a long time.
I think what I have to do is try to get it to look something like

$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{A}{n}\right)^n$$ for a suitable $A$ and apply the standard limit $$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{A}{n}\right)^n = e^A$$ I am stuck though.

Answer (score 1):

First note that as $n\to\infty$ we have
\begin{align}
\frac{t+ \log^2(n)}{t-\log(n)}
&\sim-\log(n)\\
&\to-\infty
\end{align}
hence $e^{\frac{t+\log^2(n)}{t-\log(n)}}\to 0$.
Since $\log(1+\varepsilon)\sim\varepsilon$ as $\varepsilon\to 0$, by taking logarithm, we have
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\log\left(1-e^{\frac{t+\log^2(n)}{t-\log(n)}}\right)^n
&=\lim_{n \to \infty}n\log\left(1-e^{\frac{t+\log^2(n)}{t-\log(n)}}\right)\\
&\sim -ne^{\frac{t+\log^2(n)}{t-\log(n)}}
\end{align}
By taking logarithm again:
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\log\left(ne^{\frac{t+\log^2(n)}{t-\log(n)}}\right)
&=\log n+\frac{t+\log^2(n)}{t-\log(n)}\\
&=\frac{1+\log(n)}{t-\log(n)}t\\
&\to -t
\end{align}
Consequently,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-e^{\frac{t+\log^2(n)}{t-\log(n)}}\right)^n=e^{-e^{-t}}$$

Comment: I am so terribly sorry but I made a typo.

Comment: Answer updated.